# Python wmi c.Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Processor win7 error

Tags: python, windows-7, wmi

```
>>> for i in c.Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Processor():
...    print i
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\work\pythonsv\vendor\wmi.py", line 1029, in __getattr__
    return getattr (self._namespace, attribute)
  File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 496, in
__getattr__
    raise AttributeError, "%s.%s" % (self._username_, attr)
AttributeError: <unknown>.Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Processor
```

Anyone could explain this traceback? Made a remote call on WIN7 machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

this worked: i.e. at cmd --> lodctr /q

[link] http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/perfmon-problems-unable-to-add-counters/e90f231d-0014-457d-8b1f-5f342971597a

Answer (score 0):

AttributeError means that the object `c` doesn't have an attribute `Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Processor`.

The "" indicates that Python asked `c` to describe itself and `c` returned the string "" (which obviously isn't terribly helpful). It appears you've created `c`, so it would illuminate the problem more if you would include the code that created `c`.

My best guess is that `c` is some sort of WMI wrapper, but that WMI object doesn't have the Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Processor function/method/attribute.

The underlying cause is that either you're not using `c` as designed (maybe you're missing some run-time components) or `c` isn't initialized properly.

Comment: You are right. c is a WMI wrapper, i.e. c=wmi.WMI(). The problem is, i get the related attributes on WinXP machine but not on a win7 machine. Any inputs why?

Comment: Follow-up questions should be asked as a new question.

Comment: well.. that was my original question really.. as in the title 'win7 error'.. thx btw..

Comment: It looks like this guy gets an equivalent error: http://www.vistax64.com/powershell/30302-gwmi-invalid-class-error.html