# python: wmi: Why Win32_Processor LoadPercentage on remote servers returns 'None'?

Tags: python, wmi, processor

Why when I run this query on a remote server's CPU's LoadPercentage, it return 'None'?

```
import wmi
c = wmi.WMI('192.168.1.11',user='user',password='password')
x = [cpu.LoadPercentage for cpu in c.Win32_Processor()]
print str(x)
```

Returns: 'None'

The remote server is Win7 machine.  What needs to be enabled in that particular target?
Doesnt even acquire the values on local machine too: c=wmi.WMI(). But other properties such as status, availability, etc is showing up.
I even tried [c.Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Processor class but it didn't acquire any attributes.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076755/python-wmi-c-win32-perfformatteddata-perfos-processor-win7-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked: i.e. at cmd --> lodctr /r

[link] http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/perfmon-problems-unable-to-add-counters/e90f231d-0014-457d-8b1f-5f342971597a